# Fonts in Ubuntu are not rendering in any application, just showing some boxs

Tags: 18.04, graphics, libreoffice, fonts

I just open the calendar, and Ubuntu is showing me this kind of box box all over the application and no application with graphics, like gimp, LibreOffice, inkscape, nothing is rendering properly.

[image]

I am using 18.04

I am getting this error while i am typing `gnome-calender` in terminal

[image]

and here are my `locale`

[image]

Comment: The first thought is that you need to install a font which is capable of rendering your language. Which display language are you using?

Comment: See now. Looks perfectly fine, so my initial theory seems to be wrong. Let's remove the redundant previous comments, btw.